# How to display an entire image the bigger as possible in page (no scroll) maintaining its aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, css, image-resizing, window-resize, image-scaling

I have a page layout with two columns. The first one is 80% width and the other one is 20%. I want to display an image in the first column as big as possible. The problem is that if I use width:100%; and height:auto; for this image and I resize my window until I get a shorter window, the window hides the bottom of the image.

Problem:

[image]

Desired Behaviour:

[image]

I know that I cannot get both height and width 100% at the same time maintaining the aspect ratio, but I would like to know what would you do to keep this image as big as possible in every case?

Ideally it would use width:100% on vertical screens and height:100% on horizontal ones (switching from one option to another while resizing the window) but not sure which would be the best option to do it. Maybe checking if the window height is lower than the image and then change the image dimensions?

How would you do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
    body {
  background:url('http://dummyimage.com/1080/9494ff/0011ff.png') #A98436 no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

try this code. It covers the whole portion of screen. You cannot get same throughput over different aspect ratio but background-size:cover offers the best possible support. And if you want to dig deep, you can use either picture element with multiple src attribute or use [media queries for different aspect ratios](http://robandlauren.com/2014/04/03/aspect-ratio-media-queries/).

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the image in a `div` tag and give it an `id` of full

Then

and give the value of this `div` tag in css as 100vh

hope this helps

Comment: that would be bad for different screens. vh always pose larger problems with different aspect ratios if done over static content.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your image bottom to be hidden then use height:100%

Now if you want this `width:100% on vertical screens and height:100% on horizontal ones`

Then you might need to check if height is greater than width then use height:100% else width:100% in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This won't necessarily work exactly how you want it to, but as long as the image is never *skinnier* than the container, it should *appear* to work how you want it to.

Basically you just put a mix-width and a max-height on the image, then it will always shrink either way while maintaining the aspect ratio.

Like I said previously, the only problem with this answer is that the image won't stretch to the container size if it is smaller than the container (always use images that can fill the container at the largest possible width, or use svg's)

([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cLdw8ecf/))

```css
/* This CSS is for the purposes of this demo only, not relevant */                                                    html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; } .left, .right { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; float: left; height: 100%; } .left { width: 20%; background: #aaa; } .right { width: 80%; background: #bbb; }
```

```html
<div class="left">
    <img src="//placehold.it/400X400" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;" />
</div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

---

The following is a demo of how I would actually achieve what you're trying to achieve using JavaScript. If this solution works for you, I'll update with a better explanation.

([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h61qbwy1/1/))

```js
var r = document.getElementById('resize');
var p = r.parentNode;
window.onresize = window.onload = function() {
    if(r.className.indexOf('full') < 0 && r.clientHeight < p.clientHeight) {
        r.className += ' full';
        r.className = r.className.replace('fill ','');
    }
    else if(r.className.indexOf('full') >= 0 && r.clientHeight > p.clientHeight) {
        r.className += ' fill';
        r.className = r.className.replace('full','');
    }
}
```

```css
.full {
    width: 100%;
}
.fill {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

/* This CSS is for the purposes of this demo only, not relevant */                                                    html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; } * { margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 0; } .left, .right { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; float: left; height: 100%; } .left { width: 20%; background: #aaa; } .right { width: 80%; background: #bbb; }
```

```html
<div class="left">
    <img src="//placehold.it/100X300" class="full" id="resize" />
</div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It works good, but the problem, as you say, is that I also want the image to be as big as possible... I guess I'll need to use javascript... :/

Comment: @DRBT All you would have to do is figure out the largest screen size that you're going to support, find 20% and give yourself a margin for error and there you have your image size. So even if you supported a massive 2560x1600, the image would only have to be (2560 * .2 = 512)px wide + margin. So a 600px wide image would work perfectly for you.

Comment: If you wanted to go all out, you could use the [largest display size listed on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_display_resolution#WHUXGA), 7680x4800. Which would make your image width (7680 * .2 = 1536)px. But that would be a pretty large screen.

Comment: @DRBT I've edited my answer to include a JavaScript solution at the bottom. If that works for you I'll include a better explanation.